# Videos stop playing on mobile, browser thinks that the video is still playing

Tags: javascript, html, web, video, mobile

## The problem:

On my website [mrgigi.me](https://mrgigi.me), I have 3 videos that start playing once the videos are visible in the viewport with javascript's `.play()`/`.pause()` API.

However, after a few seconds of playing the videos they all freeze on a frame. Checking in the console if the videos are paused with `videoID.paused`, returns the boolean `false`.

Meaning that the browser still thinks that the video is playing without any problems.

Using the play/pause buttons also do not work after the video freezes.

---

### A few things to be noted:

- This *only* happens on mobile, on desktop it works perfectly fine.
- I am using an iPhone 13 Pro on, at the time of writing, iOS 15.4.1
- I tried different mobile browsers which include:

  1. The default browser, Safari
  2. DuckDuckGo Browser
  3. Brave Browser
- This *only* happens when the website is deployed/hosted (so going to the website's domain). It works perfectly fine when using a local server like [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer)
- For hosting, I'm using Firebase and Cloudflare

All the code can be found on the GitHub repository: [DarthGigi/mrgigi.me](https://github.com/DarthGigi/mrgigi.me)

---

### Here are a few videos demonstrating the issue:

1. [Video showing the bug](https://cln.sh/Vk4NpA)
2. [Video showing the console output](https://cln.sh/Lr5GnZ)

---

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there was nothing wrong with the code but with the hosting platform I was using, Firebase.

I do not know what the problem exactly was with Firebase, so I switched to [Vercel](https://vercel.com/) (GitHub Pages would have fixed it too).

Thanks to [Jack Latimer](https://github.com/r1) for helping me find the cause of the problem and also providing a fix for it!